# After upgrade to Play 2.5.0: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application

Tags: scala, playframework

I tried to update my app to Play 2.5.0. All tests with `OneAppPerTest` don't run anymore. The app does not run anymore either. I can start the app with `sbt run`, but my first request brings the same error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application.
```

I do have a mix with DI and traits and it works properly in play 2.4.6.
I have no clue where to search now. Does anybody has the same problems?

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.<init>(MyController.scala:30)
  at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.class(MyController.scala:30)
  while locating com.myproject.controllers.MyController
    for parameter 7 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:79)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:220)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:220)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:86)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:86)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:86)
        at com.myproject.model.dao.DAOSlick$class.dbConfig(DAOSlick.scala:11)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.dbConfig$lzycompute(MyController.scala:30)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.dbConfig(MyController.scala:30)
        at play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfig$class.driver(DatabaseConfigProvider.scala:142)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.driver$lzycompute(MyController.scala:30)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.driver(MyController.scala:30)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.driver(MyController.scala:30)
        at com.myproject.model.dao.JavaTimeMapper$class.$init$(JavaTimeMapper.scala:20)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController.<init>(MyController.scala:30)
        at com.myproject.controllers.MyController$$FastClassByGuice$$b68ea36a.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
```

Here is my DAOSlick Trait, which is using the deprecated `Play.current`:

```
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

trait DAOSlick {
  protected lazy val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]("default")(Play.current) // this is line 11, where it fails
  protected val driver: JdbcProfile
  import driver.api._
}
```

Here is the head of "MyController":

```
@Singleton
class WebsocketController @Inject() (redis: RedisService, notificationService: NotificationService) extends SecuredController with SomeService {
```

Both, the injected Service `NotificationService` and the Trait `SomeService` are extending the DAOSlick Trait.

Can anybody give me a hint, how to change the dependency in my `DAOSlick` to `Play.current`, please?

Comment: have you checked migration guide? https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25

Comment: Did you also upgrade play-slick to version 2.0.0?

Comment: yes. upgraded play-slick to 2.0.0. And yes, checked the migration guide. The only thing I changed is the logback configuration file.

Comment: Pretty much the same issue. Play.current should work at least, but sadly not.

Comment: Have you tried `protected lazy val driver: JdbcProfile` ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [DatabaseConfig via Global Lookup](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/PlaySlick#DatabaseConfig-via-Global-Lookup) is out of date. Instead of using a global lookup, I suggest to switch to dependency injection altogether:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

class SomeDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  // dao stuff...
}
```

Not sure if global lookup is still a thing anymore... Probably not with the deperecation of `Play.current`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I see, that dependency injection is the new, preferred way how to do this.
But all my services and controllers are using Traits as well. All tests rely on that. I hoped, that I could switch to the new Play version without changing so much (almost everything).

I mean: The old API is deprecated, but should still work.